# Getting the source code of a dynamic blogger webpage

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Blogger/Blogspot has this wonderful dynamic template. I prefer using the standard templates, but I like the mosaic dynamic page design a lot. Is it possible to get the source code of mosaic template and use that as a homepage in the standard template?

I tried doing it, but it just came loading and not loaded.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to try these steps. I do many blogger templates to use it on normal blog template html.

Just go to your blogger **edit html page** after applying **dynamic template**.

Now copy the whole code and save it in text document.

Change the extension of text document **.txt to .xml**

Now we are converting the xml to html which is very easy.

Here is [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp) article and help with this you can easily convert the xml to html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to modify some xml, and it will do the trick.

Comment: You should probably expand on this answer; it's incredibly vague in its current form.